# modify TasksByKanbanState.html rally script for a specific end user

Tags: javascript, rally

Can someone provide some guidance on how to modify the TasksByKanbanState.html rally script for a specific end user?  An input for the username would be useful.

Comment: Do you want something like a dropdown box that had users in it and you could see the tasks they own after selecting that user?

Answer (score 1):

ability to select a user from a drop list will work.